# Is there a maven command line option for offline mode?

Tags: java, maven

You can specify in your maven [settings](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file that you want to run in offline mode, but is there an equivalent command line option?

I would imagine something like e.g.

```
mvn install -Dmaven.offline.true
```

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Specify offline mode via `-o`/`--offline`:

```
mvn -o install
```

[Maven book reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-offline-option)

Comment: and you can find that by `mvn -h` :)

Answer (score 22):

Just a simple:

```
mvn --offline
```

In the future, I recommend referring to `mvn --help`.

Answer (score 20):

Maven's offline mode is invoked using `mvn -o`.

However, that alone may not be enough, because sometimes the current project refers to artifacts which are not yet present in the Maven local repository cache (`~/.m2/repository`). Attempting to build that project in offline mode will fail, because needed dependencies are missing and cannot be downloaded.

So there is another useful goal:

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

This is a great command to run before hopping on a plane, which will improve your chances of `BUILD SUCCESS`. See the [go-offline documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) for details.

Answer (score 9):

`mvn -o` works in most of cases but in some cases it will not enough as from Maven 3 a downloaded  artifact from a remote/central repository creates a `_remote.repositories` file in your local repository with a reference about where the dependency was downloaded.
It may causes some issues if later you don't have access to this remote repository during your builds.
A  workaround that may work is using `mvn -o -llr yourGoal`.

From the help documentation :

```
 -llr,--legacy-local-repository         Use Maven 2 Legacy Local
                                        Repository behaviour, ie no use of
                                        _remote.repositories. Can also be
                                        activated by using
                                        -Dmaven.legacyLocalRepo=true

 -o,--offline                           Work offline
```

Another way to execute mvn in an offline way is deleting these `_remote.repositories` meta data stored in the directory of the downloaded dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Try -o, or even --help to get help with all options