# Is it possible to work with a spring java project without internet necessity?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Hello brothers in code.

Always when I try to work with no internet connection (some times this goes down in my network) I do a question to myself... "There's a way to configure a spring maven java project without internet connection necessity?"... So, since the first time that this doubt come to me I'm searching this answer in Google and never found it. What you all, Jedis of the coding, could say to me about this?

Since now I'm very thankful for the help

Answer (score 1):

This is a general question, so I'll try to provide a general answer

In a nutshell, Spring itself does not require an internet connection at runtime in a sense that it is not supposed to contain code that goes "somewhere on the internet" and queries for something.

However, Spring has a lot of dependencies (actually just like your own project probably has dependencies) so that Maven will have to bring them from somewhere upon the first run.

So Maven (that you've mentioned as a build tool) by default **will** require an internet connection.  Of course, there are many options to overcome this "difficulty" all of them boil down to making all these dependencies available so that you'll be able to compile the project without going to the internet.

The actual solution can vary:

- List item "install Nexus/Artifactory" that will act as a proxy and will download dependencies for you. It makes sense if your network infrastructure has an option to connect to the internet from some servers leaving your "developed machine" connected only to the internal network.
- Download the whole Maven repository with some crawler (it exposes web interface) to your machine and use it there (if you work for organization that doesn't have any kind of internet connection)
- Just come to the place that has an internet connection with your PC, compile everything once, Maven will download all the dependencies and cache them in your local m2 repository. So next time you'll be able to build your project even without internet connection.

I know the last option sounds more like a joke, but it also technically works if you, say a student that doesn't have any connection at home but wants to try this "Spring thing" out :)

Comment: Or just execute `mvn dependency:go-offline` within the project. If you do only a compile, Maven will only download what's necessary for compiling. However, if you then want to execute e.g. unit tests, it won't have those dependencies. go-offline will download every dependencies for every possible target that you could execute in the project.

Comment: this is the point that I would like to know, I'll try it. Thankx

Answer (score 0):

You can find some more information about mavens offline flags in this post f.e.: [Is there a maven command line option for offline mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851424/is-there-a-maven-command-line-option-for-offline-mode)