# Use dependencies from local .m2 folder if nexus is down

Tags: maven, nexus

My setting.xml file is configured to download the artifacts from remote nexus. I observe frequent problem with my VPN access. Ideally, If maven is not able to find artifact from remote repo, It should start looking under .m2 which is doing well.

Now main problem is time delay, If my VPN is up as well as nexus, my build gets complete in 1 min. But if VPN is disconnected, it takes around 8-9 minutes.

How can i fix this issue i.e reduce time.

Thanks,

Comment: You can tell Maven to build offline: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8851424/927493